# Conditionally negative definite functions on free groups

Tags: operator-algebras, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. I call a function $\ell\colon G\to [0,\infty)$ a conditionally negative definite (cnd) length function if

- $\ell(g)=0$ iff $g=e$,
- $\ell(g)=\ell(g^{-1})$,
- $\sum_{g,h\in G}\overline{\alpha(g)}\alpha(h)\ell(g^{-1}h)\leq 0$ whenever $\alpha\colon G\to\mathbb C$ has finite support and $\sum_{g\in G}\alpha(g)=0$.

Here is a reformulation that might be closer to what people in geometric group theory study: If $\ell\colon G\to [0,\infty)$ is a cnd length function, then there exists a (real) Hilbert space $H$, an orthogonal representation $\pi$ of $G$ on $H$ and a map $b\colon G\to H$ satisfying the $1$-cocycle identity
$$
b(gh)=b(g)+\pi(g)b(h)
$$
such that $\ell(g)=\lVert b(g)\rVert^2$. The triple $(H,\pi,b)$ is essentially uniquely determined by $\ell$ if we assume $H$ to be minimal, i.e., $H$ is the closed linear hull of $\{\pi(g)b(h)\mid g,h\in G\}$.

Conversely, if $(H,\pi)$ is an orthogonal representation of $G$, $b\colon G\to H$ satisfies the $1$-cocycle identity from above, $b(g)=0$ iff $g=e$ and $\lVert b(g)\rVert=\lVert b(g^{-1})\rVert$, then $\ell(g)=\lVert b(g)\rVert^2$ defines a cnd length function on $G$. So there seems to be some connection between cnd length functions and group cohomology, but I am missing the background in this field.

By Schönberg's theorem, these functions are related to isometric embeddings into Hilbert spaces, and there is also a connection to NC Lévy processes on the group von Neumann algebra $L(G)$.

Now let $G$ be a free group of rank at least $2$. If we take the usual symmetric generating set, then the graph distance to the neutral element in the Cayley graph is a cnd length function by a result of Haagerup.

**Question:** Is there a full characterization of cnd length functions on non-abelian free groups? If not, can someone at least give some more examples?

Comment: You already provided a full characterization. The question is quite vague, depending on what you mean by "characterization".

Comment: @YCor I was hoping for a more explicit description in the case of free groups. Tbh, I I don't think I know a single example of a cnd length function on $\mathbb F_2$ that is not a multiple of the one from the question.

Comment: there are a lot of "stability" results for CTN functions. For instance if $\psi$ is CTN, then so is $\psi^c$ for all $c\in [0,1]$. More generally $f\circ\psi$ is CTN for every Bernstein function $f$ (this is an old result, see §2.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509527 for the definition of Bernstein function and references).

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I should have been aware of this. In terms of the associated semigroups of ucp maps on $L(G)$, this construction corresponds to subordinate semigroups. But are you aware of any examples on free groups that are not "derived" from the one in my question (I know the notion of "derived" is vague)?

Comment: Even on $\mathbf{Z}$, there's a CND function that is neither bounded nor proper (this also holds for nonabelian free groups, but for a more trivial reasons: just use an unbounded isometric action factoring through a proper quotient).